# Self-Sacrifice is the Only Way to Beat Him - Reality Check

Tags: internal-consistency, combat

Disclaimer: This question might be in the wrong place. I wasn't sure if this is the case, so please flag it for migration and let me know if it belongs somewhere else.

I am writing a novel. In the novel, there is a battle in which two people fight to the death, using swords. At some point during the battle, it becomes apparent to the hero (who is one of the combatants) that the only way he can defeat his enemy is to sacrifice himself. There is no way out of this conclusion; it is the *only* way to slay the enemy.

**How can I make this realistic?** To the uninformed reader, I could say just about anything about swordplay and he'd accept it. If the reader happens to know a thing or two about combat, I will probably have a problem. I want to make sure I can convince those informed few as well.

This battle is central to the entire novel. The hero *must* realize that he has to sacrifice himself, and this *must* be the only way to kill the enemy. Additionally, the hero will die in this attempt. If any of these things are not true, then the entire novel will fall apart. This is the most important scene in the novel; I have to get it right.

**Details:**

- The combatants are fighting in an arena. The arena can be as large or
  small as necessary, but it has to be enclosed. I can compromise on
  the shape of the arena if needed (it is currently circular).
- Both combatants are using a version of [long-sword](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longsword). It is my
  understanding that these swords can be held in one hand, but have the
  room for two hands when delivering powerful blows. If this is
  incorrect, please let me know.
- The enemy is not human. He is slightly taller, and slightly stronger,
  than the hero. He does not wear armor, but possesses a skin which can
  only be cut by either of the long-swords.
- The hero does not have access to steel or metal of any kind (save his sword), meaning that the best armor he can possibly have is toughened leather.
- The hero is in a state of minor malnourishment, and could also be
  short on sleep, if necessary.

Comment: This should go on Writers

Comment: Something like the Deep Magic from Before the Dawn of Time? (Narnia reference.)

Comment: @Aify [writers.se] is about *how* to write, not *what* to write. I'm not sure this would do well there. That said, we do share one mod with them (Monica Cellio)...

Comment: @Aify this question would be very much off topic on Writers. That's my main SE site, so I know that.

Comment: What to write is off topic here too - this question is too story based. I also can't see any relation to **worldbuilding** in this question...

Comment: You said nothing about potential supernatural elements in the story -- make your Hero to Harry Potter, who (involuntarily) keeps his arch enemy alive by having a part of his soul in him. Adjust the soul part for whatever magic/technology/religion exists in your universe, and, for death to actually stick to your baddy, the hero's got to die, too.

Comment: I think the rationale you are looking for is not written in the question.  Specifically, you are focusing on a sword fight.  There's not many situations in a proper fight where the only way to win with your weapon is to kill yourself.  In fact, the suicide bomber vest is the only one I can think of.  Other than that, we could talk about what mistakes were made in the battle.  A mistake on the bad guy's part could open up an attack such as this, but we'd need to better understand the style of combat and their skills.

Comment: A major factor in this would be understanding the drives and goals of the bad guy.  Given that there are no "proper" ways to sword fight which give your opponent the opportunity to kill you, your bad guy would have to choose to diverge from "proper" style due to a mixture of his goals and his personality.

Comment: @CortAmmon That was my fear. The idea is that every strategy relies on attacking while keeping yourself defended. If the hero discards that and attacks with only the goal of killing the enemy no matter the consequences, then is it plausible that the enemy could be stuck? A situation of 'you can block the attack, or the one that comes after, but not both'?

Comment: @ThomasMyron It is plausable, and it does happen.  However, virtually every existing strategy stems from "don't get stabbed" first, and "attack the opponent" comes second.  If the opponent is fighting "correctly," they should merely deflect the hero's attack, or perhaps poke and prod him during the attack.  However, nothing is to say the opponent might be fighting incorrectly.  If the opponent is in a hurry, they can make such a mistake, but we'd need to understand the bad guy's mindset to understand what sorts of mistakes are made.

Comment: @Aify the reason I put the question here is because it is asking how I can make a fictional scene plausible. If there was a military strategy SE, I'd put it there instead. I'm not sure where else I would put this question...

Comment: An example might be a taunting posture that the bad guy knows he can defend from against any attack, as long as the hero is not-suicidal.  No self respecting swordsplay teacher would ever teach this as a good idea, but it's possible the bad guy's own ego gets in the way.

Answer (score 3):

Make him commit a mistake, as a result of which he'll die anyway.

For example he could trip, see the blade coming, life flashes before his eyes, etc.

If that doesn't fulfil the requirements - it isn't exactly a sacrifice if he's dead anyway - use stamina. The hero can hold his own for now, because he's faster, yet he cannot strike deep and still evade the enemy's blade. But he is losing strength quicker than his enemy, so he realizes drawing out the fight means he'll lose. He's going to risk it all on one strike on the off chance that he's fast enough to evade the block and lucky enough to survive the counter (spoiler: he's not). That still isn't really a sacrifice, unless he also had the chance to surrender.

There's also the good old "get hit, grab enemy's sword by the blade, kill enemy with a mighty slash". While not terribly believable, it's believable enough that it's been used before. And your version would be more believable than most because the protagonist actually dies while doing that. [Link to a version where the protagonist survives](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SVaslN1NiT0).

Comment: You're right - dying anyway wouldn't work. Your last paragraph was more or less what I was originally thinking though. If I can say that and have it be perfectly plausible, then I have it made. Thanks!

Comment: @Thomas Let's hope somebody with actual swordfighting experience (preferably from frequent life and death battles, but I guess we'll settle for a non-lethal practitioner too)  adds some flavor :)

Comment: Isn't there a saying that the swordmaster is most afraid of the novice?

Comment: if you make it clear the other guy is just that much better a swordsman it will be believable. That and you have to make the audience beleive the sacrifice is worth it. If the antagonist surviving  doesn't really affect anyone but the hero it will seem forced.

Comment: Stamina is probably the easiest way to go: you could add blood loss from some cut(s) sapping the hero's strength. This bars the option of stalling for an opening, because the hero is going to be the one leaving themselves open first due to the onset of weakness. The options are thus to run or die. Eliminate retreat (lots of ways to do this), and that leaves dying in vain or launching a suicidal strike; imagine the hero ignoring the enemy's strike instead of blocking or evading it, which gives just enough time to drive their sword through the opponent's head/heart/something else vital to life.

Comment: there is always the old broken sword bit, hero's sword breaks has to take the hit to close the distance and stab the enemy with the broken blade.

Answer (score 0):

There are times when dying for the greater good works.  Many Chinese movies have all the protagonists dying and usually it is to forward the concept of doing what is best for the greater good. (*Hero* comes to mind.) GRR Martin has no problem killing off his main protagonists and that has certainly been hugely successful for him.